# Disable floating tabs visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tabs, docking

Is there a way to disable floating tabs in Visual Studio 2012?

I am flicking back and forth between the xaml and code-behind windows and another application, and every now and then the code-behind window decides to de-dock itself. It may be due to (accidental) dragging on the tab bar/tab header, but I'm sure it sometimes does it for no reason at all.

This is really irritating as there is no visual cue that a tab has floated, and I don't notice til I hit Alt-Tab and find myself in a different VS window, instead of the other application.

I notice that there was a problem with VS2010 floating tabs on double-click, but it appears that 'feature' has been turned off in VS2012 (as well as, unfortunately, the option to prevent it in power tools for 2012).

I have noticed this setting in Tools/Options/Environment, but it doesn't seem to stop the behaviour, it simply makes the floated tab 'Always on Top' [image]

So, is there a way to force tabs to remain docked / prevent them from floating?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe there is a way to stop the float.

To put any floating toolbar back in it previous position, Hold the CTRL key and double click the window title bar.